# Android stackoverflow recursion

Tags: android, recursion, stack, overflow, cpu

that's the problem I've ran into. I have noticed that liner recursion like

```
public void memtest(int i){
Log.d("memory", i + ""); memtest(i+1);}
```

gets an error on i = 566 because of the
threadid=1: stack overflow on call to Ljava/util/Arrays;.checkOffsetAndCount:VIII

int should use only 4 bytes (2.21 kbytes total+links)

Is it a system that forbid app using CPU or recursion is to hard for mobile apps? 
Hopefully, I need a lot more complicated tasks like Lee algorithm (with at least 4 (even 8) calls per task)

```
protected void volna(int x, int y, int k) {
   field[x][y] = k;
   if ((x != finx) & (y != finy)) {
       if ((x > 0) && (field[x - 1][y] == 0)) volna(x - 1, y, k + 1);
       if ((x < map.getWidth()) && (field[x + 1][y] == 0)) volna(x + 1, y, k + 1);
       if ((y > 0) && (field[x][y - 1] == 0)) volna(x, y - 1, k + 1);
       if ((y < map.getHeight()) && (field[x][y + 1] == 0)) volna(x, y + 1, k + 1);
   }
```

So, is it a bad idea to use recursion and what are restrictions of CPU usage?

Thank you in advance,

Andrey

Comment: How deep recursion can go?

Comment: I've heard that stacks has a limit to about 12 kb, right? Yet, it used only 2+ kb

Answer (score 1):

Recursion is not the problem,
Yet the way you implemented it seems to be the problem.
A recursion - Must have a stop point .
Every time you use a recursion the calls to the functions are registered in the stack. if there are too many or it never stops. The stack will overflow.

A recursion - does not use too much cpu not more then a normal function,sometimes its even a better solution then a normal function.

Comment: The issue was to estimate when it crashes. And the moment, when it does so, seems to be too early. I mean it should have crushed after thousends of calls. Yet, I've reached only 600.

Answer (score 0):

You can use recursion no problem, but if the recursion never terminates or simply goes too deep (the depth of the stack has a set limit that you're not allowed to exceed), you'll get the error you're seeing. It's not a CPU usage issue.  If it's the former problem, you obviously need to fix it so it will end.  If it's the latter, see here for a solution:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_overflow#Very_deep_recursion

Comment: The issue was to estimate when it crashes. And the moment, when it does so, seems to be too early. I mean it should have crushed after thousends of calls. Yet, I've reached only 600. Even less. Is it normal to crash after 600 calls?

Comment: I have no idea, sorry.